# Simultaneous Read/Write Android Encryption additional bytes & repitition

Tags: android, encryption, byte, aes, simultaneous

I'm currently trying to securley read, cipher then encrypt the same file simultaneously (for security reasons). The code I've written below almost achieves this but adds additional bytes to the decrypted file. The decrypt method is almost exact apart from c.init is in DECRYPT_MODE.

```
    public static void encryptFile(String path, byte[] key) throws Exception {

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");

    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    byte[] output;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int totalBytes = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = raf.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        int len = buf.length;
        if (bytesRead < len) {
            byte[] out2 = c.doFinal(buf, 0 , bytesRead);
            raf.seek(totalBytes);
            raf.write(out2);
        } else {
        output = c.update(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        raf.seek(totalBytes);
        raf.write(output);
        }
        totalBytes += bytesRead;
        }
    raf.getFD().sync();
    raf.close();
    }
```

**Decrypted example**

> Some graduates could end up paying
>   back double their original student
>   loans under the new fees system in
>   England, figures calculated for the
>   BBC suggest.
>
> The figures, by leading accountants,
>   show that a student borrowing £39,000
>   for a three-year course
>   \Ü¯]£^**z§DþÒÐùN\Ü¯]£^**z§DþÒÐùNree-year
>   course ree-year course could pay back
>   up to £83,000 in total, in cash terms.
>
> Under the regime, due to begin in
>   2012, graduates will pay back 9% of
>   their earnings for up to 30 years.
>
> The government says the system is fair
>   and From 2012, univeable to charge up
>   to £9,000 per year, which will paid up
>   front by the government but paid off
>   once the student starts earning
>   £21,000 or more.

It debugs and functions as I would expect, I'm still confused as to how these bytes/repetition are getting here. (Possibly padding or incorrect doFinal)
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :]
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the issued seemed to be that I am not taking into account that the last 16 bytes of each update was being appended to the next call. By adding 16 bytes to raf.seek we stay congruent with the data and append doFinal correctly. Also using output.length seems to grant the correct parameters to the file pointer.. md5s of in and output are exact so seems to work! :] decrypt function uses raf.setLength(totalBytes+output.length);

```
    public static void encryptFile(String path, byte[] key) throws Exception {

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKeySpec k = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path, "rw");

    byte[] buf = new byte[128];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    int totalBytes = 0;
    byte[] output;
    while ((bytesRead = raf.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        output = c.update(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        raf.seek(totalBytes);
        raf.write(output);
        totalBytes += output.length;
        raf.seek(totalBytes+16);
    }
    output = c.doFinal();
    raf.seek(totalBytes);
    raf.write(output);
    raf.getFD().sync();
    raf.close();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the original file has length `L` then the encrypted file will have length `L+delta` because of padding. Then, when you decrypt it in-place, you will write out `L` correct bytes but there will still be `delta` bytes remaining at the end of the file.

If you call `raf.setLength(totalBytes)` after your while loop your should get the correct result.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply! It would seem like the problem still persists when adding the above to both the enc and decrypt methods. Using the example file the last line now reads: 
"The government says the sysnµø‰V„¦£] =ëy3o9¹ÝæçÀüæ<Åqê[ÍºÂ4Ÿ9±í™hÞ
2·þ¬rçÓ-o\.³ê{pb ÐÐ(ÚTiòZÙ¬jø¿“!õ}­qjsŸnà,ƒq| äL9Ç(‰7@(‹pÎÆÄžŒ›È5ú8!õùZiõh¡Ä_–_ð>Ó™" Aswell as holding the repetition mid-file in the previous example. However the addition does seem to reduce the file size to its original size, as before it was rounded up in multiples of 16. I'll continue to fiddle, thanks again :]

Comment: Ah interestingly catching javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block corrupted.. It would seem my doFinal is incorrect, work in progress :]

Comment: @Skitch: I should have been clear that you only add the `setLength()` call to the decrypt function.